# InteractiveDataDisplay.WPF: How to display the value on the graph

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using this library in my project [InteractiveDataDisplay.WPF](https://github.com/Microsoft/InteractiveDataDisplay.WPF).

I want to display the value in the tooltip when I hover over the graph line, but I don't know how.

XAML of my graph:

```
<Grid>
        <wpf:Chart
            Margin="10"
            IsHorizontalNavigationEnabled="False"
            IsVerticalNavigationEnabled="False"
            LeftTitle="Высота (м)"
            BottomTitle="Значение ветрового давления (Т/м²)">
            <Grid>
                <wpf:LineGraph x:Name="linegraphNorm" 
                               Description="Нормативная нагрузка"
                               Stroke="Green"
                               StrokeThickness="3"/>
                <wpf:LineGraph x:Name="linegraphCalc" Description="Рассчетная нагрузка" Stroke="Red"
                               StrokeThickness="3" />
            </Grid>
        </wpf:Chart>
    </Grid>
```

The code in which the values ​​are to be filled,

here variables normResult and calcResult are Dictionary(double,double):

```
            var graphic = new Graphic();
            graphic.linegraphNorm.Plot(normResult.Values, normResult.Keys);
            graphic.linegraphCalc.Plot(calcResult.Values, calcResult.Keys);
            graphic.ShowDialog();
```

Now my tooltip looks like this:

[image: now]

I want my tooltip to look like this:

[image]

Can anyone advise me a simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: `Description="whatever you want to see"`

Comment: @Sinatr I need the value of the graph at the current point, on which I hovered the cursor.